# Does spring boot application read application config values of another jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Does spring boot application read application config values of another jar?

If Yes, What happens if both jars have different configs, and also the precedence incase the same property exists with different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does not load the application.properties from dependent jars.  To understand where Spring loads properties from and the order by which they can be overridden, see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)